# Debug mulitple instance of project in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell, debugging, startup

I have a project in Visual Studio (VS) which I need to launch twice with different args. These 2 instances communicate and I need the debugger attached to both.

Currently I:

- Hit F5 launching one instance in debug mode
- Manullay run the `.exe` from the build output to start second instance
- In VS go to `Debug` -> `Attach to Process` -> choose second instance

Is there a way to configure Visual Studio to launch 2 instances?

If not, is there any way I can shorten the time (using powershell or batch scripting etc.)?

**Note**: *sometimes I debug with more than 2 instances. Compounding my problem*

Answer (score 2):

If you want to debug multiple instances of the same project, you can run multiple instances of the Visual studio, and run each one in different Visual Studio. It's not very comfortable, but it can helps

Comment: This would be better than my current way of doing it, Thanks. Only thing is if I launch a 3rd, that means 3 VS instances. My poor machine will take shots :)