# How do I start/debug multiple instances of the same project with different launch profiles with 1 click?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a Visual Studio C# project, and I would like to run/debug multiple instances of that project *with different launch profiles for each instance*. As this is something that I will be doing very frequently, it's important that I be able to run the projects with as few clicks/keystrokes as possible, ideally just 1.

I am aware of a handful of "almost" solutions that don't quite work, so I'll mention those and why they don't work for me:

- [It is possible to run multiple projects simultaneously when clicking the run/debug buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3850044/44003), but this dialog does not appear to allow me to run multiple instances of the same project.
- [It is possible to right-click on the project and select Debug->Start New Instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53216031/44003), but Visual Studio doesn't allow me to change the launch profile while already debugging. (Plus that's a lot more clicks than I'd like.)
- [It is possible to start the project multiple times and then attach the debugger to each later](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13381234/44003), but I need the debugger attached to each from the very beginning. (Plus that's also a lot more clicks than I'd like.)
- There is the very handy [SwitchStartupProject](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-141975.SwitchStartupProject) Visual Studio extension, but I have been unable to get it to successfully launch multiple instances of the *same* project.
- [It is possible to run multiple instances of Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38143248/44003), but that will hog a ton more resources and, yet again, require too many clicks.
- [It is possible to create a "dummy" project that runs the EXE of the main project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56061852/44003). This is the closest solution I've found, but it has the problem that it's tied to the location of the EXE built by the main project, so if I change the main project from Debug->Release (or vice-versa) then I have to first select the dummy project, swap its own launch profile to one that points at the correct EXE location, and swap back. This is a lot more work than I'd like to do for something I have to do so frequently. (In theory I could change both the Debug & Release configurations of the main project to output to the same location, but I have other tooling that assumes the default output locations.)
- [This is very easy to do if using Jetbrains Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Creating_Compound_Run_Debug_Configuration.html), but of course that requires switching to Rider, which is not something I'm ready to do right now.

Any ideas?